# Why is my most recent commit in Gitlab inconsistent with the branch history?

Tags: gitlab

I can see in the screenshot below that I pushed to the feature branch feature/contact-page 9 minutes ago but cannot see this commit in the branches history. The most recent commit in the branches history was authored 37 minutes ago. How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The most recent commit was authored in a *local* branch 37 minutes ago. This is the timestamp at which you ran the `git commit -m "recaptcha added"` command or its equivalent.

Then, 9 minutes ago, this commit was pushed to a *remote* repository on gitlab. This is the timestamp at which you ran the `git push` command or its equivalent.

This is what happens when you make a commit then wait for 28 minutes before pushing it. If this doesn't sound right then you should probably compare your local (`git log`) and remote commit history to see what exactly went wrong. Maybe you accidentally committed to a wrong branch or local/remote time settings are incorrect.

For the lack of better documentation, see [How dates work in Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-dates?view=azure-devops) from Azure DevOps on MSDN:

> - **Author date:** when a commit was originally authored. Typically, when someone first ran git commit.
> - **Commit date:** when a commit was applied to the branch. In many cases it is the same as the author date. Sometimes it differs: if a commit was amended, rebased, or applied by someone other than the author as part of a patch. In those cases, the date will be when the rebase happened or the patch was applied.
> - **Push date:** when a commit was pushed to the remote repository in question. This date is specific to the remote version control system you are using, and won't be available in your local repository.